# HTML form doesn't post or retrieve values

Tags: php, html, forms

This is a standard HTML/PHP form. My code looks fine but for some reason, the echo statement (standard debug measure) doesn't work. Any ideas why?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
Symbol: <input type="text" name="symbol" />
<br />
Start Date:
<select name="month_start">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<br />

...
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $SYMBOL = $_POST['symbol'];
    echo "$SYMBOL";
    $MONTH_START = $_POST['month_start'] - 1;
    echo "$MONTH_START;

?>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean echo statement? Do you mean this <?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?> ?

Comment: Where is `$_POST['submit']` set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 issues - first your form action should be `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>`, second, you have a syntax error in your 2nd echo statement, should be `echo "$MONTH_START";` (You're missing the closing quote, although you don't need the quotes if you're only echoing the variable.) and lastly, you need to add `name="submit"` to your submit button when you're post variable contains the proper submit key for your display condition

Comment: There we go. That name="submit" was what I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing with name="fieldname" on each input fields

Answer (score 2):

Well I noticed you're missing a closing `"` on the last echo, instead change to:

`echo "$MONTH_START;"` (assuming it wasn't a typo)

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting `$_POST['submit']`, so it will never echo anything.
Test if a field (that you're using) is set:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['symbol'])) {

   $SYMBOL = $_POST['symbol'];
   echo "$SYMBOL";
   $MONTH_START = $_POST['month_start'] - 1;
   echo "$MONTH_START";
}
?>
```

Comment: @drbr0wn Good. Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the tick under the answer score :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get any value in the `action` property, you have to put an echo in from of the variable, like so: `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`. 
However, this will not help, because you could just do this `<form method="post" action="">`, and it would still POST to the same page.

Secondly, you need an extra `"` in the last line, making it `echo "$MONTH_START";`.

Also, the variable you are trying to catch, will never be set, because it's not part of you form. Try using `print_r($_POST);` to see.

You get two variables: `$_POST['symbol']` and `$_POST['month_start']` - you should really be checking if one (or both) of them are set, before taking any action.

Hope it helps! :)